# 2 table query - select from each and report from both

Tags: mysql

My platform: Ubuntu 12.04
I have in my database:
- table1: box, tray, ...
- table2: tray, bolt, ...

I've tried this sql query:

```
select `tray`,bolt from table2 where `tray` in ( select `tray` from table1 where `box` > 11 );
```

gives me a list of trays and bolts.

I would like to have: box, tray and bolts as output. How?

thanks in advance. A pointer to a good tutorial for extra credit? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an inner join instead of IN() :

```
SELECT t.tray,t.bolt,s.box
FROM table2 t 
INNER JOIN table1 s 
 ON(t.tray = s.tray and s.box > 11)
```

As @Reto mentioned, [you can read about joins here!](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

In general: to get data from more then 1 table , you have to either use JOIN, or use a sub query in the select.

A solution with a sub query(correlated query) :

```
SELECT t.box,t.tray,
       (select s.bolt from table2 s where s.tray = t.tray) as bolt
FROM table1 t 
WHERE t.box > 11)
```

Comment: And the tutorial about the different ways to join two tables/entities: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: I marked this as correct because I understood it 1st (use of "using" was perplexing at 1st.) Also the tutorial that helped most is @ https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `JOIN`:

```
select t1.box, tray, t2.bolt
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     using (tray)
where t1.box > 11;
```